# How to properly free memory inside a function that increases the rows of a 2D char array

Tags: c, realloc

I have a function that increases the rows of a 2D char array, which does contain elements in it. Am I supposed to free the memory after using `calloc`? How do I do that inside the function? I am getting memory leaks and I think it may be due to me not using `free`.

```
char **decode_structure;

    void make_row_decode_structure_bigger(int rows){
        //printf("inside the making the rows bigger \n");
        int max_rows = rows+1;

        char **store = realloc( decode_structure, sizeof *decode_structure * (rows + 1) );
        //printf("after a store has been assigned\n");  
        if (store){ 
            decode_structure = store;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++ ){

                decode_structure[rows + i] = calloc(15, sizeof(char));
                decode_structure[rows + i][0] = '\0';
            }
        }
        //printf("end of making the rows increase\n");
        return;

    }
//in main()
decode_structure = (char**)calloc( 2, sizeof(char*) );


        for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        decode_structure[i] = calloc(15, sizeof(char));
        decode_structure[i][0] = '\0';
        }
```

here is the error message that showed up:

*** Error in `./prog': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x0000000001937010 ***

Comment: Apologies forgot to include that.

Comment: `for(size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++ ){` iterates once.  It that intended?  Where is `make_row_decode_structure_bigger()` called.  A [mcve] would be more clear.